# values-sw resource issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have two devices:

1. `Moto-G first generation (720*1280, 4.5" 324.2 PPI)`
2. `ICE Tablet (600*1024 7" 169.55 PPI)`

And created folders `"values-sw420dp-xhdpi"` and `"values-xhdpi"` for `Moto-G` and folder `"values-sw360dp-mdpi"` for `ICE Tablet`. But both devices taking the values from `"values-sw360dp-mdpi"` folder.

I am very confuse about this behavior of the devices because both are quite different, however why this is happening ?

Can anybody please guide me how to define `sw` folder for these two devices and in general how `sw` is working? I read the official guide line of `sw` folder and supporting multiple screens, but did not got exact idea.

Comment: I Guess.sw420dp-xhdpi means screenWidth =  840(420 *2) ,sw360dp-mdpi means screenWidth = 360(360*1).I think you should get the screen dpi of those two device.

Comment: Nexus - 4 (768 x 1280 pixels - XHDPI (~318 ppi pixel density)) takes values from values-sw720dp. Really surprised.... Checked using https://github.com/intuit/sdp library.

Comment: I got it.  values-sw720dp = values-sw720dp-mdpi = 720.And 768>720.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, let me cite a fragment from Android Developers Guide:

> **Screen configuration: smallestWidth**
>
> **Qualifier values:** swdp
>
> **Examples:** sw600dp sw720dp
>
> The fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest
>   dimension of the available screen area. Specifically, the device's
>   `smallestWidth` is the shortest of the screen's available height and
>   width (you may also think of it as the "smallest possible width" for
>   the screen). You can use this qualifier to ensure that, regardless of
>   the screen's current orientation, your application's has at least `<N>`
>   dps of width available for its UI.
>
> For example, if your layout requires that its smallest dimension of
>   screen area be at least 600 dp at all times, then you can use this
>   qualifier to create the layout resources, `res/layout-sw600dp/`. The
>   system will use these resources only when the smallest dimension of
>   available screen is at least 600dp, regardless of whether the 600dp
>   side is the user-perceived height or width. The smallestWidth is a
>   fixed screen size characteristic of the device; **the device's
>   `smallestWidth` does not change when the screen's orientation
>   changes.**
>
> Full Text:   [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Like @tiny said:

> sw420dp-xhdpi means screenWidth = 840(420 *2) ,
>
> sw360dp-mdpi means screenWidth = 360(360*1)

EDIT: Using this site http://pixeldensitycalculator.com/ I've already calcualated that

- Moto G 1st edition has density 293.72 ~ 320dpi
- ICE Tablet has density         169.55 ~ 160dpi

None of these devices doesn't have more than 320dpi, that's why none of them using your 420dpi folder.

Hope it help

Comment: Not getting you why "Both of your devices have the same screen density" ? Both have different resolutions and different screen sizes. Can you please explain it by calculating it?

Comment: Also if both devices have same screenWidth = 360, but both belong to different resolution. One is mdpi and second one is xhdpi. But hoever why it is ignoring the fact of that?

Comment: Yes you correct now for dpi calculation. I also used the same things, but what is the solution for that? I want to define different values folder for height of layout. Is there any solution?

Comment: Check this link: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/. For example, clik launcher icons add yours preferred and it automatically would create all needed layout folders.

Comment: Consider of using all screen densities in your project. Read a lot articles like above 'Supporting Multiple Screens'. Check Android Design Guides

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But I am not talking about icons, I just want to define different values folder as I mentioned in above comment. e.g. 50dp height for Moto-g and 80dp height for 7 inch tablet.